# crop a character from an image using java

Tags: java

How can crop and display a character in an image without using mouse?
The image contain only a one charater and nothing else.
Example a scanned copy of a paper, which contain a character drawn on it.

Comment: *"How can crop and display a character in an image without using mouse?"*  ..A track-ball or laser pointer is fine, right?  (or to put that another way)  Why the arbitrary constraint?

Answer (score 1):

This will require some image processing, and there is a lot of libraries available for this task. General processing sequence would be:

- convert image to b&w image
- calculate integral image over it
- using integral image determine glyph boundaries

( if nothing of the above make sense to you,  read some image processing books first )

Answer (score 0):

You could get Slick2D library and then use the SpriteSheet class to crop it. It works like this:

```
SpriteSheet s = new SpriteSheet("imagelocation");
Image cropped = s.getSubImage(x,y,width,length);
```

Worked for me :D